# .SetDataSouce() do Crystal Report dando erro NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Olá.

Eu estou fazendo um relatório simples para teste usando  Crystal Report com c#.

O relatório é carregado por um arquivo .ttx;

No controller eu coloquei:

```
 public ActionResult ObterRelatorio()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] relatorio = new byte[] { };

            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}.pdf","Relatorio"));

            List<QuestaoDTO> lista = QuestaoDTO.ObterRelatorio();
            RelatorioDeQuestao relatorioDeQuestao = new RelatorioDeQuestao();

            relatorio = relatorioDeQuestao.ObterRelatorio(lista);

            return File(relatorio, "application/pdf");
        }
        catch (Exception excecao)
        {
            TempData["MENSAGEM_ERRO"] = excecao.Message;

            return View();
        }
    }
```

Nele eu passo uma lista de objetos.

Quando eu vou carregar o relatório dá um erro NullReferenceException no .SetDataSource(), mesmo com a lista sendo trazida da forma correta.

```
public byte[] ObterRelatorio(IList<QuestaoDTO> listaDoRelatorioDTO)
    {
        try
        {
            Stream fluxoDeDadosDoRelatorio;
            int tamanhoDoFluxoDeDados;
            byte[] vetor;

            Relatorio.SetDataSource(listaDoRelatorioDTO);
            fluxoDeDadosDoRelatorio = Relatorio.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
            tamanhoDoFluxoDeDados = Convert.ToInt32(fluxoDeDadosDoRelatorio.Length);
            vetor = new byte[tamanhoDoFluxoDeDados];
            fluxoDeDadosDoRelatorio.Read(vetor, 0, tamanhoDoFluxoDeDados);

            return vetor;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception excecao)
        {
            throw new Exception(excecao.Message);
        }
    }
```

O que pode ser?

Editando, mostrando como ele traz a lista:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: aparentemente o que está nulo é o Relatorio (ali antes do SetDataSource), onde você está inicializando ele?

Comment: Não traz vazio, editei o post colocando uma imagem pra mostrar

Comment: mas não me refiro a lista, disse aquele 'Relatorio' ali em Relatorio.SetDataSource

Comment: Desculpe a demora!! Então, vi que o objeto Relatorio estava vazio mesmo, depois que funcionou... obrigada!